# What is this large, fast-growing plant with red stems and leaf veins?

Tags: identification

I thought this was a red beet, but I am not so sure, as it got huge very quickly. It has red veins all over it.

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This looks like [Amaranth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amaranth). It's also called 'Pigweed' and this plant is tremendous for nutrition.  Amaranth is a very cool plant.  It is called a Wonder Food known by even our ancestors.

This is an Amaranth.
[image]
[Source](http://www.goodcook.de/wp-content/uploads/2013/03/amaranth-pflanze.png)

This looks like your Amaranth plant.
[image]
[Source](http://duffitness.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/10/Amaranth.jpg)

Comment: Amaranth was my first thought too - couldn't post because the question was on hold. So +1 for you instead :-)

Comment: Thank you!  I mean to question Niall????  Took a big breath and, well.  I have learned so much about this plant, probably should grow this guy!!

Comment: It's not just the seed that's nutritious. The leaves are great to use too. You can use them in different ways like you'd use spinach.

Answer (score 1):

It is an Amaranth, but it's called a "Pink Beauty"! I have two of these plants.